# Как в git игнорировать только модификациии?

Tags: git

Было у меня устройство с неким функционалом и в ходе работы над ним было принято решение завести 2 таких устройства, разделив задачи первого между ними. Далее были небольшие доработки которые привели к 3 версиям прошивок для двух устройств. Захотелось мне собрать все эти версии в одно дерево, чтобы было удобно сравнивать изменения во всём этом веере. В итоге получилось следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3 варианта прошивок на 2 одинаковых устройства с разным функционалом. Для каждого устройства есть файл с настройками IDE и поскольку устройств 2, то без git им просто дали разные имена EX1 и EX2.

По факту это мусорные файлы, которые копят настройки интерфейса в IDE и их изменения не нужно фиксировать. И сейчас собирая все эти проекты вместе, я не могу просто засунуть EX1 и EX2 в .gitignore т.к. тогда, переключаясь между ветками 1 и 2 устройства, EX1 и EX2 появятся в одном месте. Но в то же время, при любом изменении в интерфейсе ide, git сразу же увидит изменения в файлах EX и предложит сделать коммит.

Пробовал искать инфу, но я чего-то даже коротко сформулировать это не могу.
Единственное, что смог найти, это использовать git update-index --skip-worktree , после этого git перестаёт предлагать закоммитить EX1/EX2, но при этом переключаться между ветками он тоже не даёт (Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout).
Извините мб вопрос очень тупой, но я с гит начал работать позавчера.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что у вас должно быть 7 отдельных проектов. *"не хочу плодить бесконечные коммиты из-за работы с ide"* - тут не понятно, о чем речь. И вообще, конкретики в вопросе явно не достает.

Comment: "По факту это мусорные файлы, которые копят настройки интерфейса в IDE и их изменения не нужно фиксировать." - нужно было изначально эти файлы в .gitignore добавить. Сейчас их нужно из проекта удалить, закоммитить, добавить в gitignore.

Comment: Я так пробовал. Но они должны таскаться каждый за своим проектом со статичным именем и менять содержание не триггеря git по этому поводу.

Comment: Настройки IDE в принципе не должны включаться в проект.

Comment: Понимаю. Просто вся проблема в разных названиях этих файлов, а переименовывать их, это значит во всех 6 проектах переподключать связи. Поэтому думал у git есть метод который позволит таскать по веткам файлы не следя за их содержанием.

Comment: `git rm --cached <file>`?

Comment: Ветки нужны для параллельной работы, чтобы потом смержиться. Вы просто не  по назначению `git` используете. В чём проблема создать сабмодули?